# What is the Meaning of the Notation

Tags: complexity-theory, machine-learning

What is meant by saying an algorithm runs in time $Poly(|S|,n,\frac{1}{\epsilon})$.

Can somebody explain with an example.

Comment: This is hard to answer without any context. Notation often depends upon the context in which it is used. Will not migrate to [CS.SE] until the question is improved.

Comment: @DaveClarke: I don't think this is ambiguous; Schaull's answer is exactly right.

Comment: @HuckBennett: Perhaps it is simply a matter of unfamiliarity on my part (and the OP's).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that there exists a polynomial $f(x,y,z)$ such that the algorithm runs in time $f(|S|,n,\frac{1}{\epsilon})$.

Specifically, it means that there are constants $c_1,c_2,c_3\ge 0$ such that the algorithm runs in time $O(|S|^{c_1}\cdot n^{c_2}\cdot (\frac{1}{\epsilon})^{c_3})$.

Comment: In the big O, why is it multiplying the parameters rather than adding them?

Comment: Because that's how polynomials work - you're allowed to multiply factors by one another. To make this a little more concrete, think of a polynomial $f(x,y,z)$, then $x\cdot f(x,y,z)$ is also a polynomial, and then you have to multiply the monomials by one another.

Comment: Thanks, so then conceivably you could also have something like: $O((|S| + someconstant)^{c_1} \cdot (n - 2)^{c_2} * (\frac{1}{\epsilon})^{c_3})$ as well?

Comment: Yes, certainly.